# Laravel add to cart button with same product into cart with +1 quantity

Tags: ajax, laravel, modal-dialog, e-commerce, cart

I am new to Laravel. Add to cart button to add same product into cart with +1 quantity.
Trying to check if stock greater than qty. When one item is qty 3 than 2 stock I would like to display some text "The requested qty is not available" instead of form submit. Is this possible?

Total Stock have 2.

The problem is that more add to cart to same product into +1 quantity. Nothing prevent add to cart “The requested qty is not available”. can anyone help me please.

In Controller

```
    public function add_to_cart(Request $request)
        {
            $name = $request->product_name;
            $price = $request->product_price;
            $itemno = $request->product_itemno;
            $qty = $request->product_quantity;
            $color = $request->product_color;
            $size = $request->product_size;
    
            $stock = products::join('stocks', 'stocks.pid', 'products.id')
            ->join('sizes', 'sizes.pid', 'products.id')
            ->where([['products.item_no', '=', $itemno],['sizes.size_name', '=', $size]])
            ->first();

            // Current stock quantity
            $stockqty = $stock->qty;
            if($qty <= $stockqty)
            {
             echo "<p>was successfully added to your shopping cart</p>";
    
             Cart::add([
                'id' => $itemno,
                'weight' => 500,
                'name' => $name, 
                'price' => $price, 
                'qty' => $qty, 
                'color' => $color, 
                'size' => $size
                ]);
            }
            else
            {
             echo "<p>The Requested quantity for this product is not available.</p>";
            }
            
        }
```

In Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

$(document).on('click','#add_to_cart',function (e) {
    
        var cart_count = $('.navbar-tool-badge').text();
    cart_count = parseInt(cart_count);
    
    if($('input[type=radio][name=size]:checked').length == 0)
      {
         $('.msg').html('Please choose size.');
         return false;
      } else {
    var product_name = $('#hidden-name').val();
  var product_price = $('#hidden-price').val();
  var product_itemno = $('#itemno').val();
  var product_quantity = $('.quantity').val(); 
  var product_color = $('#color').val();
  var product_size = $("input[name='size']:checked").val();
  
e.preventDefault();
 
$.ajax
({
method:"POST",
url: "{{ route('add_to_cart')}}",
 data:{
  "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
   product_name:product_name,
    product_price:product_price,
     product_itemno:product_itemno,
      product_quantity:product_quantity,
       product_color:product_color,
        product_size:product_size},
cache: false,
success: function(response)
{
$("#getCode").html(response);
$("#myModal").modal('show');

} 
});
}
 });
 
 
});
```

Comment: So where's the issue? You can replace the `echo` with `return response()->json(['message' => 'Some message']);` and handle the message in the frontend to display to the customer

Comment: echo or response()-> is similar. it is better to use echo when sending data to an ajax call. Qty 4 using session. Total Stock 2. I want to prevent add to cart with same product into cart with +1 quantity than total stock 2. Like display: "The requested qty is not available". It should be always grater than the qty in order to get the success msg. start to add to cart with one quantity than total stock 2. like display: was successfully added to your shopping cart

Comment: So you are doing the check `if($qty <= $stockqty)` right? Whats not working then

Comment: $qty is not about currently session. $qty gets the value of an input field number. I want to check how to less qty(currently session) than total stock.

Comment: Are you storing the current cart quantity for each product in session? If so you can get the value out of session via the key. If not you can pass the cart info back to the `add_to_cart` function when making the ajax call

Comment: yes. please give me the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the value for each product quantity added to cart in the session, whenever `add_to_cart` is executed. Something like below should work.

```php
public function add_to_cart(Request $request)
{
    //You should get only the id of the product and cart from the frontend
    //via ajax request
    //Then you should fetch the Product record from database for that id
    $product = Product::findOrFail($request->pid);
    $cart = Cart::findOrFail($request->cid);
    $sessionKey = "Cart-{$cart->id}-{$product->id}";
    $session = $request->session();
    $requestedQty = $request->product_quantity;
    $desiredQty = 0;
     
    //Get the stock data
    $stock = products::join('stocks', 'stocks.pid', 'products.id')
        ->join('sizes', 'sizes.pid', 'products.id')
        ->where([
            ['products.item_no', '=', $itemno],
            ['sizes.size_name', '=', $size]
        ])
        ->first();
    
    // Current stock quantity
    $stockqty = $stock->qty;

    //If the requested quantity is greater than the available stock
    //when the product is added for the first time, send out of stock    
    if($requestedQty > $stockqty) {
        echo "<p>The Requested quantity for this product is not available.</p>";
    }

    //When a product is added for the first time session won't have entry
    if(empty($session->get($sessionKey)){ 
        $desiredQty = $requestedQty;       
        $session->put($sessionKey, $requestedQuantity);
    } else {
        $desiredQty = $session->get($sessionKey) + $requestedQty;
    }

    if($desiredQty > $stockqty) {
        echo "<p>The Requested quantity for this product is not available.</p>";
    }

    //Overwrite the session entry with the new quantity
    $session->put($sessionKey, $desiredQty);
   
    echo "<p>was successfully added to your shopping cart</p>";
    
    Cart::add([
        'id' => $itemno,
        'weight' => 500,
        'name' => $name, 
        'price' => $price, 
        'qty' => $requestedQty, 
        'color' => $color, 
        'size' => $size
    ]);
            
}
```